# Foreground background colour solid while the image still being transparent

Tags: css, background-image, parallax, background-foreground

I have a simple build of a parallax site and I am trying to layer one background image over another. The foreground image is basically the logo with a transparent cut out, and the cut out is the only part of the background image I want to be displayed on the screen.

The rest of the first slide should be a solid colour.

I want to do this so that it maintains the best quality of the foreground image as possible, scaling it as a % doesn't look half as good.

The site is here for demo http://www.designandintention.com/Raikon/

HTML in question so far:

```
<div align="center" class="slide" id="slide1" data-slide="1" data-stellar-background-ratio=".7">

<div align="center" id="menuwrapper">

<div align="center" id="slidemenu">
<div id="hrs">
</div>

Raikon Property Development

</div>

</div>

<div id="slideforeground" data-stellar-ratio="0" data-stellar-vertical-offset="0"alt="">

</div>

<a class="button" data-slide="2" title=""></a>

</div><!--End Slide 1-->


CSS:

.slide{
    background-attachment: fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
.wrapper{
    width:960px;
    height:200px;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
}
.slideno{
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;font-weight:400;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    font-size:100px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}
#menuwrapper {
width:90%;
height:0px;
}

#slideforeground{
background-image:url(../images/Foreground.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center; 
height:100%; 
width:100%; 
}

/******************************
 SLIDE 1 
*******************************/
#slide1{

    background-color:#e3e8cf;
    background-image:url(../ribahighgate-dexigner-james.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

Comment: please provide the code for what u have so far.

Comment: The demo link looks good to me in Chrome, assuming the greenish 'Our passion - Raikon - Design and Build' is the foreground cutout image. What exactly is the problem with it? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi Yochannah, I've changed the foreground picture to cover the screen, which isn't what I wanted. I want to put a small picture in the centre of the screen with the same background colour surrounding it, without losing the PNG's transparency

Comment: Hi Jamie, Is this what you were trying to do http://jsfiddle.net/naeluh/k9dx2/ I just changed a few things - instead of a background Img via CSS I added the img to the div nofocus and set a rule for #nofocus img {z-index:1;position:fixed;} let me know thanks If that is correct I can post the answer